# Prototyping in jQuery using $.fn on native functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

In context of this question, lets assume I used

```
(function($){
//stuff I did in order to prototype in here
})(jQuery)
```

Now, I know how to define new functions, but I tried my best to change .position(), and nothing worked. My questions are:
 1. What does .position() return? Because it returns some object that contains the top and left position of the element in whose context it was called.
 2. Can you add any method to this already-function? Like, this.position().MyNewMethod(), that pops a "Hello!" alert on the screen?
 3. Or, as extension of 2, is it possible to make this.position().MyNewMethod() return ( this.position().top + 50 )?

Comment: *"tried my best to change .position"* ... to do what and where's the relevant code? Sounds like you need to study how to create jQuery plugins. Lots of tutorials around for that

Comment: Ok, so .position returns an object with 2 properties, top and left. Lets call that object OBJ. If I want to add a function to do something with those properties, do I need to create such function with $.fn that can be usable by any object, or is there some way to attach it to the OBJ that .position returned (or all objects of this type)?